# How to Find Out Where Mathematica Is Installed?

Tags: installation, ubuntu

I should have written down where I installed Mathematica on my Ubuntu 18.04 system, because I need to get to that folder.. Is it possible to do this? I went to `/home/user`, but I cannot find the folder there, but I *do* have Mathematica installed and I *can* use it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you used `Directory[]`? The path is contained in `$InstallationDirectory`

Comment: You said you can use Mathematica. Open it, and type $InstallationDirectory in a cell. Evaluate that cell and it will reply with the direcvtory where it is installed.